# Fetch API with parameters not working on Edge 14

Tags: ecmascript-6, microsoft-edge, fetch-api

I'm using `fetch` in my application for requests and [the polyfill](https://github.com/github/fetch) for browsers that don't support it. I've never had problems until now (the app works on Edge 13, IE, etc).

More specifically, on Microsoft Edge 14 `self.fetch` exists so the polyfill doesn't apply. If I call fetch with one parameter such as `fetch('/api/users')` it works, but calling it with 2 parameters (I need to set some headers, the method, etc)

```
fetch(request.url, {
    headers, 
    method: request.method || 'GET',
    body: request.body || null
})
```

it doesn't work. It doesn't even make the call, doesn't throw an error, nothing. I've been googling for an hour and so far no luck. Any ideas?

The obvious would be to do a dirty check of the useragent and override the native function with the polyfill, but I'd like something more "elegant". Maybe I'm doing something wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so I found an answer with the help of [this post](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/8546263/). Apparently it was crashing when trying to send a `body` parameter on a `GET` request even if it was empty or undefined.

So I'm just making a check first for the method, and if it's a GET I'm not adding the body anymore. This fixed my problem

Answer (score 0):

Anyone else who gets stuck with this:

Check your version of Edge, 17 doesn't support Promises, upgrade Windows with the October 2018 update which includes Edge 18 and Promises are supported, fetch requests will work.

https://www.microsoft.com/ja-jp/software-download/windows10

Comment: Well, this was not the issue here. The issue is that certain versions of Edge (14-17) don't allow setting a body as parameter. This includes `null`. If you set it to `undefined` or not at all it works.
Furthermore, this is a case of a production website that has to support all kinds of platforms and users, you can't just tell users to update

Comment: I know this isn't the best solution but Microsoft's official advice is to tell users to upgrade. Just added this answer since it solved my issue and could help others.